# $\overline{x}$ is nilpotent in $R[x]/\langle x^n-a\rangle$ where $a$ is nilpotent in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **[Dummit and Foote, Exercise 7.4, problem 14.(d)]** If $f(x) = x^n - a$ for some nilpotent element $a \in R$, prove that $\overline{x}$ is nilpotent in $R[x]/(f(x))$.

To show that $\overline{x}$ is nilpotent in $R[x]/(f(x))$, we have to show that for any $g(x) \in R[x]$, $x+g(x)f(x)=x+g(x)(x^n-a) \in (x^n-a)$. To use the nilpotency of $a$, I have taken $nk$-th power of $x+g(x)(x^n-a)$, where $k$ is the smallest natural no. such that $a^k = 0$. But this is giving me $x^{nk} + g'(x)(x^n-a)$, where $g'(x) \in R[x]$, leading me to nowhere close to the desired result. It'd be appreciated if anyone can help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{f(x)} = 0$, $\bar{x}^n = \bar{a}$.

And, since $a$ is nilpotent, for some natural number $m$, $a^m = 0$.

Finally, $\bar{x}^{mn} = \bar{a}^m = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to bring in $g(x)$, or $g'(x)$.

The elements of a quotient ring $S/I$ are cosets of the form $r+S$, with $r+S=r'+S$ if and only if $r-r'\in S$, and operations defined via representatives:
$$\begin{align*}
(r+S) + (t+S) &= (r+t) + S\\
(r+S)(t+S) &= (rt) + S.
\end{align*}$$

To show that $\overline{x} = x+(f(x))$ is nilpotent, you need to show that there exists $n\gt 0$ such that $(x+(f(x)))^n = 0+(f(x))$. Since
$$\begin{align*}
(x+(f(x)))^n = 0+(f(x)) &\iff x^n + (f(x)) = 0+(f(x))\\
&\iff x^n-0\in (f(x))\\
&\iff x^n\in (f(x))\\
&\iff f(x)\text{ divides }x^n\text{ in }R[x].
\end{align*}$$

And, indeed, show that since $a$ is nilpotent in $R$, there is a sufficiently large $N$ such that $f(x)^N = x^m$ for some $m\gt 0$.